# live reload 2 with rails 3.2.7 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reload, compass-sass, sass

did anybody run into the same problem with livereload in rails with compass?

```
application.css.scss Unparsed
No application integration exists for rails
```

Image of the error:

[image: http://safe-and-sound.biz/error_livereload.png]

Answer (score 0):

Please check if that helps:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/compass-users/oaI4meEp9Hs